# Linux: What is causing high interrupt activity for IRQ 23 (ehci_hcd)?

Tags: linux, performance

I run gkrellm to monitor my workstation.  Total CPU usage usually runs 0-1% at idle; when there is activity, it's usually cyan-colored (user space).  It was running clean this morning.

A couple hours ago, I noticed it was running consistently 4-5%, colored orange.  *top* shows a steady 5-6% sy (system - kernel space?), which doesn't show up as %CPU in the process table, so I can't tell from *top* what is using the cycles.

I did some googling and checked /proc/interrupts, ran *vmstat* and *sar* to check interrupt activity, etc.  Everything points to IRQ 23, which is running about 12 intr/s.  /proc/interrupts shows it as IO-APIC-fasteoi (ehci_hcd:usb1, ehci_hcd:usb2), so apparently a USB device (or maybe bus controller).  I don't have that many USB devices attached (one flash disk, a multicard reader, kbd & mouse, UPS, and the printer).  I've tried "udevadm trigger" and powered off the printer and removed the flash drive, but the sys% usage remains steady.

How can I find out why so many interrupts are being generated (what device, etc.)?

Comment: You think 12 interrupts per second is "so many interrupts"?! Ordinary mouse movement could easily generate that.